# Write-n-cite drops some data (pseudorandomally) from citations

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, citations

I'm trying to help with a case where Refworks citations are integrated to an MS Word (Office 2010 with Windows 7) document with Write-n-cite utility (version 612?).

Citations seem mostly to work but every now and them, part of the citation is automagically lost (journal name, number & pages).

No idea what could be the reason... except for not using LaTeX & BibTeX.

Comment: Can you press ALT+F9 to toggle field codes and check the fields of the incorrect citations. Are they different to the normal ones?

Comment: I asked to check this and there were no clear differences between problematic and "normal" citations